# Android Web Server that supports Cookies and Basic Authentication

Tags: android, session, web, jsessionid, ijetty

Do you know of a web server that I can install on Android (like i-jetty) that would allow hosting applications that are secured with Basic authentication and session cookies ? i-jetty seem to work but does not support session cookies (it seems).